# Docker Container failing to connect to X-Server

Tags: docker, xserver, 22.04

I have a docker container, and am wanting to use some GUI outside of the container. Problem is, when I try to open a GUI inside the container (for example firefox) it gives me the following Error (this message is from firefox):

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

I tried to change the `DISPLAY` variable to `MY_IP_ADDRESS:0`, but that didn't really do anything. I also tried to disable access controll for `xhost`.

I normally start my container via `docker-compose`, but even when I just start it via the following command it gives me the same Error:

```
docker run -eDISPLAY=:0 -t -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix ubuntu:focal
```

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and all my packages are up to date.

Comment: For me I had to run docker as root for this to work. I was using Docker Desktop which I think runs docker as non-root. Anyways there are some limitations of non-root docker which I think might be the cause, ie Host network https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#known-limitations